# Python: Creating classes that uses a dictionary

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I am creating a class that does some simple Graph Theory calculations, I created a dictionary at the bottom of the code and I want to know how can I use the dictionary in the class?

I wanted to try something like this,

```
k = Graph(d.keys())
```

but it didn't work and it gave me this error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Does anybody have an suggestions?

```
class Graph:
    """docstring"""
    def __init__(self, node, degree):
        self.node = node
        self.degree = degree

    def Add(self):
        return sum(node)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    infile = raw_input("Enter File Name:  ")
    myfile = open(infile, 'r')
    d = {}
    with myfile as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            k,v = line.split()
            d[int(k)] = int(v)
            next(f)

    k = d.keys()
    v = d.values()
```

Comment: Did you want to create a `Graph()` object for every line perhaps? It isn't clear what you expect to happen when you pass `d.keys()` to the `Graph()` constructor.

Comment: And what kind of data does the file contain when read? You need to give us more specifics as to what the input is and what output you expect to see.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return sum(self.node)` in the `Add` method?

Comment: @MartijnPieters , I am new to programming so I kind of don't know what I am doing but what I want is to import a long list of keys and represent them as "nodes".

From my understanding I can use the list "k" and and manipulate it in the class if I pass it into the "Graph() constructor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are doing here but let me take a guess:

You defined a constructor that takes 2 arguments (we dont count self):

```
def __init__(self, node, degree):
```

.. and you called the graph constructor with 1 argument:

```
k = Graph(d.keys())
```

I guess you want

```
k = Graph(k, v)
```

...but we really need to see where you are creating the Graph object.

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific but I want to represent "k" as node and "v" as degree.

The data type is a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `**` operator to unpack a dictionary into keyword arguments:

```
k = Graph(**d)
```

Comment: TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings


This is what it returned when I tried that, I have a list of integers.

Comment: You said you had a dictionary, not a list.